# why would redirecting 404 errors cause a js file to return HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, apache, mod-wsgi

I was suspicious that the issue of seeing console errors "showing HTML as JS files" was caused by my attempt to redirect 404 errors. And then a comment on [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/3gv3mq/console_logs_uncaught_syntaxerror_unexpected_token/) suggested that this was a valid assumption... But how is this possible? By what means does a JS resource *become* HTML when 404s are redirected?

[image: This redirect issue]

Answer (score 1):

Application servers usually have default web pages to render HTTP error codes. For instance, these are the [Apache 2.4 settings](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html) regarding custom error responses.

So, it's normal to get HTML responses for HTTP error codes if your application server is configured as such.

Comment: I don't see on that page where it says the error page will always be served as HTML, even if it has a different extension.

Comment: Right! The other responsible for rendering these HTML responses is the browser itself. You can verify it using curl or telnet.

Comment: I can read the entire config file that my `mod_wsgi-express` is using. Where would I see that it returns HTML responses?